# What are the last digits of Moser's number?

Tags: decimal-expansion, big-numbers

How can I find the terminating digits of Moser's number, which is 2 in a "mega"-gon in Steinhaus-Moser notation (a mega being 2 in a pentagon)?

I was able to calculate the last 6 digits by analyzing the last digits of much smaller numbers in the 2 in a polygon sequence (2 in a hexagon, 2 in a heptagon, etc.), but is it possible to calculate, say, the last 10 digits?

How many terminating digits of the Moser can be practically calculated?

Comment: Are you really sure about the last $6$ digits of Moser ? And if yes, why doesn't this approach work for $10$ digits then ?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that the Moser ends in ...301056. Trying the same approach for 10 digits, though, would take me a lot of time without a computer program for this stuff (which I don't currently have). Also, I would need the last 10 digits of 2 in a hexagon, heptagon, etc.

Comment: Since Moser is not a power tower, how can we calculate the last digits at all ? In the case of Mega this works because the number of iterations is still small. But how can we do it with Moser ? It would help a lot if you demonstrate how you did that.

Comment: I was able to find the last 6 digits of Moser by analyzing the last digits of 2 in a pentagon, hexagon, heptagon, octagon, nonagon, and decagon, and looking for patterns in those.

Comment: @Peter Last digits tend to be cyclic e.g. $2^2$ is $4$ and the last digit of $4^4$ is $6$, and last digit of $6^n$ is $6$, so we are stuck there. Though it would seem that repeating this for more digits is a very lengthy task indeed...

Comment: I found the last 3 digits by noticing that when going from 2[5] to 2[6], 2[6] to 2[7], etc., the last 3 digits always advance by 400, while the last 4 digits advance in a cycle with period 5 (2400, 8400, 4400, 400, 6400). When you go from 2[6] to 2[11], 2[11] to 2[16], etc. the last 5 digits advance by 32000.